# MVC Url.Content does not resolve file name having special characters like #@

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using MVC 5 with Razor view engine. I want to display image whose name saved in database. This is my view code:

```html
<img class="article-image" src="@Url.Content(string.Format("~/Images/Upload/{0}/{1}", Model.FolderName, Model.ImageName))" width="100%" />
```

This works ok until i have special character in Model.ImageName like 'Untitled#@.png'. I've got this in my rendered html:

```html
<img class="article-image" width="100%" src="/Images/Upload/de7b1f47-c9ec-4521-ae8d-faae518e1144/Untitled#@.png">
```

If i use URL encode for file name, image is displayed properly. This is encoded version:

```html
<img class="article-image" width="100%" src="/Images/Upload/de7b1f47-c9ec-4521-ae8d-faae518e1144/Untitled%23%40.png">
```

I also tried

```html
<img class="article-image" src="@string.Format("~/Images/Upload/{0}/{1}", Model.FolderName, Model.ImageName)" width="100%" />
```

with no luck.

I found this in MSDN about **UrlHelper.Content**:

> If the specified content path does not start with the tilde (~) character, this method returns contentPath unchanged.

I just wonder why **UrlHelper.Content** doesn't resolve my case? I don't want to encode my file name manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Url.Content` merely maps the provided relative path to a relatively absolute path that include virtual directories and such the application may be under. It doesn't do any processing to the relative URL that it's provided and it doesn't actually load any content or anything: it just returns a string.

If `FolderName` or `ImageName` might contain characters that are invalid in a URL, then you simply need to use `Url.Encode` to encode them:

```
<img class="article-image" src="@Url.Content(string.Format("~/Images/Upload/{0}/{1}", Url.Encode(Model.FolderName), Url.Encode(Model.ImageName)))" width="100%" />
```